# A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected - when sending data

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am trying to send data back to the client when the server receives "debug". ATM the following provides this error:

A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.

Added my main class to help answer questions

```
    static Socket newSocket;
    static byte[] data;
    static EndPoint tmpRemote;
    static IPEndPoint sender, endpoint;
    static int recv;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        data = new byte[1024];

        endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3000);

        newSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

        newSocket.Bind(endpoint);



        sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 904);
        tmpRemote = (EndPoint)sender;

        newSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref tmpRemote, new AsyncCallback(OperatorCallBack), data);

        Console.Read();
    }



    private static void OperatorCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        log("[" + DateTime.Now + "][New Connection] " + tmpRemote.ToString() + "");
        try
        {
            int size = newSocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref tmpRemote);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                data = (byte[])ar.AsyncState;
                string[] dataCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, size).Split(' ');
                if (dataCommand[0] == "debug")
                {
                    newSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HA IT WORKED :)"));
                    log("Sent debug");
                }
                else
                {
                    log("Invalid Command");
                }
            }
            data = new byte[1024];
            newSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref tmpRemote, new AsyncCallback(OperatorCallBack), data);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you have to open a socket first?

Comment: @BlessedGeek If that was the problem the error message would be different.

Comment: @BlessedGeek I have added my main method to the code to help answer any questions. I believe the socket is open.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues when trying to connect to sockets over a slow connection. I resolved it by making sure the newSocket.Connected property was true before any Send/Receive calls.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is quite clear. You are calling send() on an unconnected socket and without providing a target address. Where are you sending to? UDP doesn't know.

Comment: I have added my main method to the code to help answer any questions. I believe the socket is open.

Comment: @AndrewZak Certainly the socket is *open,* but it isn't *connected*, and you haven't provided a destination address by calling `sendmsg()`. You must do one of those things, usually the latter.

Answer (score 2):

As connection(socket.connect()) is not needed when you send data via ProtocolType.Udp 
that error may occur when you dont suggest the address wher UDP Message should forward

**IN YOUR CASE**
[here the address is not provided for udp Send()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCqh1.png)

**SOLUTION**

Try SendTo() instead

```
Socket soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
soc.EnableBroadcast = true;
IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 58717);
EndPoint endp = (EndPoint)ipend;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);

soc.SendTo(bytes,ipend);

soc.Close();
```